# Check if url is cached webview android

Tags: android, caching, webview

I use webview to load html pages and urls.

I want to load url only if internet is available or if the url content is cached by the web view.

> How can I check if a url is cached without having to create my own
>   cache on some external path.

```
   WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();                                                                             
   ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);                                                                                 
   ws.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);                                                          
     wv.setOnTouchListener(this);                                                                                 
   wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {                                                                      
       @Override                                                                                                  
       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {                                        
           if (!url.contains("http")) {                                                                           
               view.loadUrl(url);                                                                                 
           } else {                                                                                               
               if (Utils.isConnectingToInternet(thisActivity)) {                                                  
                   view.loadUrl(url);                                                                             

               }                                                                                                  
           }                                                                                                      
           view.loadUrl(url);                                                                                     
           return false;                                                                                          
       }
```

I have referred to :

[WebView Cache Data Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206481/webview-cache-data-directory)

[Check if file already exists in webview cache android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388989/check-if-file-already-exists-in-webview-cache-android)

[How to move webView cache to SD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389002/how-to-move-webview-cache-to-sd)

[Android webview check if page is in cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748855/android-webview-check-if-page-is-in-cache)

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Set webview cache mode LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK.

Override WebViewClient methods :

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            if (view.getUrl().equals(failingUrl)){
                showInternetConnectionError();
            }
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }

        @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            onReceivedError(view, error.getErrorCode(), error.getDescription().toString(), request.getUrl().toString());
        }
```

It will load webpage from server if internet connection available, otherwise load from cache. If webpage is not available in cache then it will display internet connection error.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `onPageCommitVisible` inside your `webviewclient`. When the URL is not cached and the network is not available, this callback will be called.

```
@Override
public void onPageCommitVisible(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url);
                if(!isNetworkAvailable){
                    //page not cached
                }
                Timber.d("Page cannot draw")
}
```

Check internet availability

```
boolean isNetworkAvailable(){
      ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

      NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
      boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                      activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
      return isConnected;

}
```

Comment: what about internet is available and it is already cached. What callback function is being used?

Answer (score 0):

Working version of @vidha 's answer without using deprecated API and in Kotlin:

```
override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest, error: WebResourceError) {
        if (request.url.toString() == view.url) {
             // showInternetConnectionError()
             webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error_state.html")
        }
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
}
```